# MongoDB java driver how to add arrays whith mixed data types

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trouble because I want to increment a date object in 1 hour, with the **java driver**, this is:

```
{"tDate":{$add: ["$tDate", 3600*1000]}
```

making, wont work because mongoDB expects a number and receives a string

```
String [] date_add_array =  {"$t_tDate", String.valueOf(3600*1000) };
BasicDBObject query_component = new BasicDBObject("tDate", new BasicDBObject("$add", date_add_array))

>exception: $add only supports numeric or date types, not String
```

Using a BasicDBList object list won't work, because I don't want an object inside the array. This would be (and is not what I want or need):

```
 {"tDate":{$add: [{"$tDate", 3600*1000}]}
```

---

What is the work around? How can I feed MongoDB with an array of mixed data types?

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335037/how-to-define-add-count-count1-aggregation-with-mongo-java-impleme

Comment: I think what the link is saying to do is to just pass in the DBList object without further wrapping that in an array?

Comment: @3rf yes, i want to pass an array/list unwrapped. 
Using DBList will place an array of wrapped objects. **I will get this with BasicDBList**: {"tDate":{$add: [{"$tDate", 3600*1000}]}, **but I want/need this**: {"tDate":{$add: ["$tDate", 3600*1000]}.

Comment: The above link seems to suggest something like 
`BasicDBList dbList = new BasicDBList();`
`dbList.add("$tDate);`
`dbList.add(3600*1000);`
might work. Again I'm just trying to be helpful, I have very limited experience with the java driver.

Comment: @3rf I will have a try at that tomorrow when I go back to the office. Cheers mate

Comment: it works, yesterday when I tried to use the BasicDBList, i could not add and int (the interface only accepts objects), today I created an **Integer object** and the BasicDBList accepted it :)